# How does YUM decide which package is the best install candidate for a dependency when there are several options?

Tags: package-management, yum, rpm, packaging, rpm-spec

I have a package that I need to be compatible with openjdk 11 and oracle java 11. I'm trying to create a metapackage that can depend on openjdk java 11 or oracle java 11:

My openjdk metapackage spec is:

```
Name:       openjdk-11-adapter
Version:    0
Release:    0
Epoch:      0
Summary:    NA
License:    NA

Provides: java-11-metapackage
Requires: jre-11 >= 11

%description
%prep
%build
%install
%files
```

The oracle java metapackage spec is:

```
Name:       oracle-11-adapter
Version:    0
Release:    0
Epoch:      0
Summary:    NA
License:    NA

Provides: java-11-metapackage
Requires: jre  >= 2000:11

%description
%prep
%build
%install
%files
```

So now my package can depend on `java-11-metapackage` and have a dependency on either version.
When I install it, I expect that `yum` would install whichever java is available.

What's ACTUALLY happening is that when I install my package through yum, I know that `jre-11` is available through `java-11-openjdk` but yum will ALWAYS try to install the `oracle-11-adapter` and complain that there is nothing to satisfy the `jre  >= 2000:11` dependency. The `openjdk-11-adapter` is definitely known to yum, but ignored.

My question is, **WHY does yum ignore the satisfiable `openjdk-11-adapter`, and instead try to install the unsatisfiable `oracle-11-adapter`? How does it determine install suitability?**

I noticed that if I renamed `oracle-11-adapter` to `aaaoracle-11-adapter`, yum will behave as expected and install the java adapter whose dependencies can be satisfied, but this feels far too hacky a solution for me to put it into production.

Comment: consider using `dnf` (DaNdiFied yum) which has a better solver algorithm.

Comment: I'm sure it does, and if I was making the package for myself I'd do that, but I have end users who I need to consider. I would rather not create a hidden dependency on dnf. I appreciate you replying though!